# let user change phone number xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have 4 `UIButton` with the following method:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:0739421700"]];
```

How can I let the user change the phone number through another `UIButton`?
So when the app is killed the button still contains that number.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see the relation to Xcode.

Comment: do you want them to manually type in the number?  Or do you want them to select from a predefined list of numbers (like button 1 calls 9999999999 and button 2 calls 8888888888)?

Comment: I want them to set 1 button to call a certain number and another button to another certain number. So when they have set that it should save so if the button is pressed next time it should call the inserted number. do you understand, my english isnt pretty good?

Comment: Are you creating the buttons in code or Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a good way to have simple persistent data. You can get the strings as you do now and then use `setObject:forKey:` to store them.